# How to show Max Window Icon (TitleBar) in ReactJS?

Tags: java, reactjs

I want to ask how to display the Sample Title Bar in the Icon Window Max section only and this is my coding.

```
import React from 'react'
import { TitleBar } from 'react-desktop/windows';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div style={{
      display: 'block', width: 400, paddingLeft: 30
    }}>
      <h4>React Desktop Windows TitleBar Component</h4>
      <TitleBar
        title="Sample TitleBar"
        controls
        isMaximized="true"
        background="orange"
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

And want to show the Icon Window Max bagian
[image]

Here is the code I got the link coding from: [Link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/react-desktop-windows-titlebar-component/)

Comment: You want to show the maximized icon?

Comment: I give permission to only show the maximized icon, the others, such as minimize or close, are not already displayed on the website

Answer (score 1):

You are seeing the window icon as `isMaximized="true"` in `<TitleBar>` props. `"true"` is also an invalid value. It needs to be a boolean -

```
isMaximized={false} // maximize icon
isMaximized={true} // restore down icon
```

You should be using state to manage this -

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { TitleBar } from "react-desktop/windows";

export default function App() {
  const [isMaximized, setIsMaximized] = useState(true);
  function toggleMaximize() {
    setIsMaximized(!isMaximized);
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <TitleBar
        title="Sample TitleBar"
        controls
        isMaximized={isMaximized}
        onMaximizeClick={toggleMaximize}
        onRestoreDownClick={toggleMaximize}
        background="orange"
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit kind-franklin-89ed69]