# How to show only Max Window Icon in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I want to ask how to display the Sample Title Bar in the Icon Window Max section only and this is my coding.

```
import React from 'react'
import { TitleBar } from 'react-desktop/windows';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div style={{
      display: 'block', width: 400, paddingLeft: 30
    }}>
      <h4>React Desktop Windows TitleBar Component</h4>
      <TitleBar
        title="Sample TitleBar"
        controls
        isMaximized="true"
        background="orange"
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

And want to show the Icon Window Max 
before:
[image]

after:
[image]

Here is the code I got the link coding from: [Link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/react-desktop-windows-titlebar-component/)

Comment: You already asked this here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72555035/how-to-show-max-window-icon-titlebar-in-reactjs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pert react desktop [documentation](https://reactdesktop.js.org/docs/windows/title-bar) they only provided support to hide/show all three control, there is no such specific prop which we can use to hide individual tool from title bar.

So if we want to hide the other two option apart from maximize we can use css and overwrite existing css in following way

```
.titlebar a[title="Close"],
.titlebar a[title="Minimize"] {
  display: none !important;
}
```

I have given class to Titlebar component and hide element using css.

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-desktop-demo-forked-p2lj0j?file=/src/styles.css:59-148)